# Crashes happend in camera plugin used in flutter modules,

Tags: android, flutter, plugins, camera, crash

- firebase crash logs one.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraDevice was already closed
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2236)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSessionInternal(CameraDeviceImpl.java:658)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession(CameraDeviceImpl.java:644)
at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera$DefaultCameraDeviceWrapper.createCaptureSession(Camera.java:175)
at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.createCaptureSessionWithSessionConfig(Camera.java:479)
at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.createCaptureSession(Camera.java:465)
at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.createCaptureSession(Camera.java:387)
at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.startPreview(Camera.java:1074)
at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera$1.onOpened(Camera.java:322)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:151)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

- firebase crash logs two.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.close()' on a null object reference
at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.closeCaptureSession(Camera.java:1192)
at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.access$500(Camera.java:100)
at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera$1.onClosed(Camera.java:342)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$5.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:255)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

two crashes caught in my firebase account.
by investigations, It happened at the camera plugin used in flutter modules,
It's happening on android devices only, versions are 9 to 12 versions.
Used plugin details:
camera: ^0.10.0
https://pub.dev/packages/camera

any one can help with this, ?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing this for sometime now.

Comment: Not yet, i hope it will fix in the flutter library level